A Feast of Shadows
Beneath the moon's watchful eye, I weave,
A silent creator, though none perceive.
Feathers in shadow, a whisper in flight,
Where black meets the edge of a pale twilight.
I feast on fragments, scattered wide,
Gathering stories that others divide.
Born in a nest, but I travel far,
To lands where pieces hold no scar.
A curious name, both hunter and feast,
In quiet places, I tame the beast.
Who am I?
Hint 1:

 I’m part fright and part delight.

Hint 2:

 I created that which has safeguarded a city for almost two centuries.

Hint 3:

 I'm directly responsible for millions of people getting lost

Hint 4:

 Even though I sell a lot, I do not have monopoly.

Hint 5:

 Isn't it time someone pieced this puzzle together?


Is it close to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shearwater ?

I don't understand what you mean by "close to", but I don't see an immediate connection between your link and the answer.

Are you

 Ravensburger, the jigsaw puzzle (and other games/puzzles) company


I don't understand many lines, such as "In quiet places, I tame the beast". Can this be elaborated?
